# Как установить расширение для SQLite на Windows?

Tags: windows, sqlite, extension

Установить расширение в SQLite, если готового файла библиотеки найти не удалось, как оказалось, не так просто. Полного и подробного гайда я так и не нашёл, так что пришлось по крупицам собирать информацию, и теперь для таких же странствующих в поисках ответов, как и я, вот 10 шагов для решения поставленной задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот полное руководство по установке расширения для SQLite на Windows:

1. Установите MinGW с GCC
2. Скачайте .c файл желаемого расширения (например, [uuid.c](https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/uuid.c))
3. Скачайте с [этой страницы](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) **Source Code** и **Precompiled Binaries for Windows**
4. Поместите файлы из **"sqlite-dll-win64-x64-XXXXXXX.zip"** (или win32) и **"sqlite-tools-win32-x86-XXXXXXX.zip"** в папку System32
5. Поместите желаемый файл **uuid.c** и файлы из **"sqlite-amalgamation-XXXXXXX.zip"** в любую папку по своему усмотрению
6. Запустите CMD и перейдите в директорию с файлом **uuid.c**
7. Введите в консоль `gcc -g -shared uuid.c -o uuid.so`
8. Если кто-либо (даже вы сами) говорит вам, что на Windows вам следует использовать расширение **.dll**, плюньте ему в лицо
9. Переместите полученный **uuid.so** файл в папку System32
10. Запустите CMD ещё раз и введите команду `.load uuid` ИЛИ введите `SELECT load_extension('uuid')` в качестве SQL-скрипта

***На этом всё!***

Comment: Вы серьезно предлагаете вместо скачивания библиотеки ставить mingw и gcc и считаете что это проще чем скачать файл и закинуть в системную папку?)

Comment: Если библиотеку легко найти в уже скомпилированном виде, то этот вариант очевиден и даже в упоминании не нуждается, так что не нужно, пожалуйста, язвить

Comment: Не очевиден, прочтите свой вопрос ;)

Comment: Ну хорошо, раз для кого-то "не очевиден", добавил уточнение

Comment: Ваш вопрос все еще звучит "Как установить библиотеку SQLite" но отвечаете вы всё еще на вопрос "как установить расширение для SQLite"